# How to use the Facebook Graph API to checking for location in facebook Page

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-fragments

I'm Integrating the Facebook SDK 3.0 to my android app, I've the facebook page Id, I want to add a check-in button to the application, action of this button is user can only checking if he/she in the place/ close to the place (500M), if not i want to show an error alert.

how do i do it with Facebook sDK 3.0 using the graph API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the page ID, you can query the graph API by sending a request to https://graph.facebook.com/page_id

The result should have the latitude/longitude of the place. You can try it out yourself by using the graph explorer

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: so once i have the lat/long for place i have to run the location service and find user current location and compare to get the final decision? is that next step i have to do,i'm using google map API2 in my project

Comment: that's correct. You can also run a search against the graph API if you start with the lat/long, and specify a distance, but since you have the ID already, you can just run location services, and check the distance yourself.

Comment: Thanks for help, i was able to complete the check in.

Answer (score 0):

Update to api requires that you do "/{pageId}?fields=location" which then returns a Location object type containing various geo fields.